# Taking A Selected Item In A Listbox and Populate Into A Textbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, listboxitems

Alright, I currently have a listbox being populated with a variety of files.

What I'd like to do is select a file, click the add button and populate the item name into that textbox.

Then, select another item, click the add button and populate that items named into an empty textbox.

I can get the first textbox to populate, but once I select the second item, I can't get empty textbox to display.

Here's my current code on how I'm populating the first textbox. The commented out section was for adding those items into another listbox, which worked but I need to specify a custom order, which I was I thought adding each item to a textbox.

```
    Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
    'Dim selectedItems = (From i In ListBox1.SelectedItems).ToArray()
    'For Each selectedItem In selectedItems
    'ListBox3.Items.Add(selectedItem)
    'ListBox1.Items.Remove(selectedItem)
    'Next

    TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem

    End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post the code that you're using to populate the listbox?

Comment: Ok, code has been added.

Comment: I don't quite get it - when you click Add for the second time, do you want to overwrite the contents of the first TextBox, or find another empty TextBox and populate it?

Comment: I want to find an empty textbox, and populate that on the second add click and so on until X amount of textboxes are filled.

Comment: How many textboxes do you have? Are you creating them dynamically or do you have defined them in your designer?

Comment: @NathanKoop I have 5 textboxes predefined. Not all will be populated and each textbox has a label, indicating which file from the listbox will get populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
    If string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then 
        TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    ElseIf string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then 
        TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    ElseIf string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text) Then 
        TextBox3.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this is highly inflexible code? What if there are 10 textboxes? What about 100?

Comment: Yeah this worked but like Nathan said, what if there were 100 textboxes. I was thinking a loop but wasn't sure how to code for it.

Comment: You can loop through the controls in "Me.Controls", look for which ones are TextBox controls, and populate accordingly. If you take this approach, you'll need to decide how to order the controls - you could order them by TabIndex or Name, but it's probably best not to use the default order in Me.Controls. For a more dynamic approach, create the TextBox controls in code and keep them in an array or list that you can loop through to populate them.

Answer (score 0):

I put a quick little demo together.

First the aspx page:

```
<asp:ListBox id="lstItems" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>-- Select --</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTextboxes" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt4" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button id="btnAdd" Text="Add" runat="server" />
```

And the code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If lstItems.SelectedIndex <= 0 Then
        Return
    End If
    For Each ctrl As Control In pnlTextboxes.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            Dim txt = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text) Then
                txt.Text = lstItems.SelectedValue
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note, that this doesn't track if you've already selected the item.